# Func<> with unknown number of parameters

Tags: c#, .net, generics, functional-programming, clr

Consider the following pseudo code:

```
TResult Foo<TResult>(Func<T1, T2,...,Tn, TResult> f, params object[] args)
{
    TResult result = f(args);
    return result;
}
```

The function accepts `Func<>` with unknown number of generic parameters and a list of the corresponding arguments. Is it possible to write it in C#? How to define and call `Foo`? How do I pass `args` to `f`?

Comment: Unfortunately not possible :( You can do it via `Delegate` and using reflection, but I am sure that is not what you want.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That's not possible. At best, you could have a delegate that also takes a variable number of arguments, and then have the delegate parse the arguments

```
TResult Foo<TResult>(Func<object[], TResult> f, params object[] args)
{
    TResult result = f(args);
    return result;
}
```

```
Foo<int>(args =>
{
    var name = args[0] as string;
    var age = (int) args[1];

    //...

    return age;
}, arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

Answer (score 21):

You can use `Delegate` with `DynamicInvoke`.

With that, you don't need to handle with `object[]` in `f`.

```
TResult Foo<TResult>(Delegate f, params object[] args)
{
    var result = f.DynamicInvoke(args);
    return (TResult)Convert.ChangeType(result, typeof(TResult));
}
```

Usage:

```
Func<string, int, bool, bool> f = (name, age, active) =>
{
    if (name == "Jon" && age == 40 && active)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}; 

Foo<bool>(f,"Jon", 40, true);
```

I created a fiddle showing some examples: https://dotnetfiddle.net/LdmOqo

---

Note:

If you want to use a `method group`, you need to use an explict casting to `Func`:

```
public static bool Method(string name, int age)
{
    ...
}
var method = (Func<string, int, bool>)Method;
Foo<bool>(method, "Jon", 40);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3ZPLsY

Comment: Does this actually work?  Does the `DynamicInvoke` reflect the Array as comma-delimited parameters into the methods execution?

Comment: Yes @GoldBishop. `DynamicInvoke` does exactly that. In [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LdmOqo) I'm showing some examples. Check msdn doc [DynamicInvoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.delegate.dynamicinvoke(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.

Comment: hmmmm...the mischief that can be had with such knowledge :)

Comment: This works, which is cool. Unfortunately you can't directly pass a method that takes arbitrary arguments, you must first create a Func. So a method `bool F(string name, int age, bool active) {...}` cannot be passed directly to `Foo<bool>(F, "Jon",40,true)`.

Comment: Nice point @yoyo. To use this function with method group you need to use explict casting. I created another fiddle showing how you can do this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qVlt47 I'll update my awnser explaining it. Thanks for comment!

Comment: Thanks for the update, and the fiddle (dotNetFiddle is great!) I've been trying to find a way of handling arbitrary parameters without needing to state the parameter types at the call site, but I've decided to find another way to solve my problem. (BTW, `Method("yoyo", 22)` definitely returns false! ;-)

Comment: @yoyo I'm glad to hear that. :)

Comment: With c# 7.3 you can define `R Foo<D,R>(D f, params object[] args) where D:Delegate` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters#delegate-constraints)

Answer (score 17):

This could become easy with [lambda expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions):

```
TResult Foo<TResult>(Func<TResult> f)
{
    return f();
}
```

Then usage could be like:

```
var result = Foo<int>(() => method(arg1, arg2, arg3));
```

Where `method` can be arbitrary method returning `int`.

This way you can pass any number of any erguments directly through lambda.

To support asynchoronous code we can define:

```
Task<TResult> Foo<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> f)
{
    return f();
}

// or with cancellation token
Task<TResult> Foo<TResult>(Func<CancellationToken, Task<TResult>> f, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return f(cancellationToken);
}
```

and use it like:

```
var asyncResult = await Foo(async () => await asyncMethod(arg1, arg2, arg3));
// With cancellation token
var asyncResult = await Foo(
    async (ct) => await asyncMethod(arg1, arg2, arg3, ct), 
    cancellationToken);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try something similar to what I posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47556051/4681344

It will allow for any number of arguments, and enforces their types.

```
public delegate T ParamsAction<T>(params object[] args);

TResult Foo<TResult>(ParamsAction<TResult> f)
{
    TResult result = f();
    return result;
}
```

to call it, simply......

```
Foo(args => MethodToCallback("Bar", 123));
```

Comment: I think it should be called `ParamsFunc<>` instead, but otherwise I agree. I would make it covariant ("`out`") in `T`. For example `public delegate TResult ParamsFunc<out TResult>(params object[] args);`

Answer (score 0):

In some cases you may be able to get away with a trick like this:

```
public static class MyClass
{
    private static T CommonWorkMethod<T>(Func<T> wishMultipleArgsFunc)
    {
        // ... do common preparation
        T returnValue = wishMultipleArgsFunc();
        // ... do common cleanup
        return returnValue;
    }

    public static int DoCommonWorkNoParams() => CommonWorkMethod<int>(ProduceIntWithNoParams);
    public static long DoCommonWorkWithLong(long p1) => CommonWorkMethod<long>(() => ProcessOneLong(p1));
    public static string DoCommonWorkWith2Params(int p1, long p2) => CommonWorkMethod<string>(() => ConvertToCollatedString(p1, p2));

    private static int ProduceIntWithNoParams() { return 5; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Although it is not really what asked, a simple workaround would be to define several Foo method with different number of type arguments.
It is uncommon to have function with more than 6 parameters, so one could define the following method and get away with almost every use case, while staying type safe. Renan's solution could then be used for the remaining cases.

```
public TResult Foo<TResult> (Func<TResult> f)
{
    return f();
}

public TResult Foo<T1, TResult>(Func<T1, TResult> f, T1 t1)
{
    return f(t1);
}

public TResult Foo<T1, T2, TResult>(Func<T1, T2, TResult> f, T1 t1, T2 t2)
{
    return f(t1, t2);
}

...
```