# Use params with Func<>

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

I would like to use a Dictionary> with a small modification. Where Func<>  can take 1 or more parameters of type double.

I would have liked to do something like this

```
Dictionary<string, Func<params double, double>>
```

Basically I would like to be able to call functions that look like this.

```
double Function1(double value);
double Function2(double value1, double value2);
double Function3(double value1, double value2, double value3);
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Func<> with unknown number of parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22834120/func-with-unknown-number-of-parameters)

Comment: Can you tell me in what context you want to do this?

Answer (score 4):

the params-keyword is only syntactical sugar when calling the function. basically the parameter is an array of values:

```
public double MyFunc(params double[] values) { // code has to handle a array of double values... }
```

So you simply have to define your dictionary as

```
Dictionary<string, Func<double[], double>>
```

If you still want to have this syntactial sugar, you should define some wrapper-function or an extension function to call the method like

```
public double Call(string key, params double[] values)
{
    return dic[key](values);
}
```