# Creating a list of methods to choose from and get their amount of parameters in c#

Tags: c#, methods

I'm creating a project similar to [this](http://karlsims.com/evolved-virtual-creatures.html) which was created by Karl Sims. Based on the [paper](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1GOBJ4M9Nka8GAU0GiXG5l6HmNq7U8AQ2) that Sims published, I understood that in order to create a "brain" for the creature I need to create a sort of neural network, which in this case is a directed node graph. I won't go into detail about the way the entire network works.

I need to creature neurons, which are nodes that receive some input values and produce one other value based on their functions. They can be pointed to, and point to **one or more** other nodes. Each neuron also has a function it uses to produce its value. The first step in creating the network is to instantiate neurons without pointers, then give each neuron a function, and then point the pointers of the neurons to its inputs (other nodes in the network). My problem is I can't link the function chosen with the number of parameters required.

For example, let's say that neurons can have these 3 functions:

```cs
    public float Sum2(float a, float b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }

    public float Mul3(float a, float b, float c)
    {
        return a * b * c;
    }

    public float Threshold(float a){
        if(a > 0.5)
            return a;
        return 0;
    }
```

Somewhere in the code, I need to have a class similar to this:

```cs
    class NeuronData{
        FunctionIdendifier func; // An object that points to one of the functions Sum2, Mul3, or Threshold. Through it I can reach the original method easily. 
        int numOfInputs;
    }
```

I thought of creating a dictionary where the keys are functions and the values are the parameters amounts, but that seems too complex, and also has room for human error.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You could use reflection to find out the parameters of a function.

Comment: @H.G.Sandhagen I've never used reflection, could you specify?

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22834120/func-with-unknown-number-of-parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used an approach similar to @Posix, I'll post the code for the complete solution. Here 10 neurons are created and get assigned a random function out of a dictionary that includes a function as a key and the parameter amount as a value.

```cs
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Neuron n = new Neuron();                
            }

        }
    }
```

The function manager:

```cs
    public delegate float NeuralFunction (params float[] inputs);
    public class FunctionManager
    {
        private static Random rand = new Random();
        private static FunctionManager singleton = new FunctionManager();

        private Dictionary<NeuralFunction,int> functionDict;

        private FunctionManager() {
            functionDict = new Dictionary<NeuralFunction, int>();

            functionDict.Add(Thresh, 1);
            functionDict.Add(Sum2, 2);
            functionDict.Add(Mul3, 3);
        }

        public static FunctionManager Singleton { get { return singleton; } }


        public float Sum2(params float[] inputs)
        {
            // 2 Inputs
            if (inputs.Length != 2)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            float n1 = inputs[0];
            float n2 = inputs[1];
            return n1 + n2;
        }

        public float Mul3(params float[] inputs)
        {
            // 3 Inputs
            if (inputs.Length != 3)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            float n1 = inputs[0];
            float n2 = inputs[1];
            float n3 = inputs[2];
            return n1 * n2 * n3;
        }

        public float Thresh(params float[] inputs)
        {
            // 1 Inputs
            if (inputs.Length != 1)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            float n1 = inputs[0];
            if (n1 > 0.5)
                return n1;
            return 0;
        }

        public KeyValuePair<NeuralFunction, int> GetRandomFunction()
        {                        
            List<NeuralFunction> keys = Enumerable.ToList(functionDict.Keys);            
            NeuralFunction function = keys[rand.Next(0, keys.Count)];
            return new KeyValuePair<NeuralFunction, int>(function, functionDict[function]);

        }
    }
```

The neuron class:

```cs
class Neuron
    {
        NeuralFunction function;
        int paramAmount;

        public Neuron()
        {
            KeyValuePair<NeuralFunction, int> keyVal = FunctionManager.Singleton.GetRandomFunction();
            function = keyVal.Key;
            paramAmount = keyVal.Value;
            MethodInfo method = function.Method;
            Console.WriteLine("-- Method: " + method.Name + "Has " + paramAmount + " Parameters");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about array as input. But it always expects float  data type.

```
float SumN(float[] args)
{
    return args.Sum();
}

float MulN(float[] args)
{
    return args.Aggregate((s, x) => s * x);
}

float Threshold(float[] args)
{
    if (args.Length != 1)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
    float value = args[0];
    return value > 0.5 ? value : 0f;
}

class NeuronData
{
    Func<float[], float> func;

    public NeuronData(Func<float[], float> func)
    {
        this.func = func;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [Viewing Type Information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/viewing-type-information) especially [ParameterInfo Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.parameterinfo?view=netframework-4.8)