# How to generalize async methods with delegate parameters in C# to reduce redundant code?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, generics, task

I have some async methods I want to try a set number of times until they return true or the max attempts have been reached, with a delay in between. I've been able to get the outcome I desire, but have not been able to reduce the redundancy.

The functions return `Task<bool>`.

The below code is what I'm trying to generalize (as only the function call line is different)

```
for (int attempts = 0; attempts < numOfTaskAttempts; ++attempts)
{
    if (!await UpdateSingleUserStatistic(sendingPlayer, PlayfabServerKeys.DailyPuzzle, request.score))
        await Task.Delay(taskAttemptDelay);
    else
        break
}
```

I tried to generalize by creating methods passing delegates (below) since the only one line differs, but for some reason, can't see a way to generalize them.

On searching this site, I first tried passing a Task instead of a delegate, but that just ran the task once.

I wrote the below methods where the signature of the Func changes as do the string arguments provided. I can't seem to find a way to make them more generic (i.e. have just one method and pass a task and/or a delegate).

```
private static async Task<bool> CallAsyncMethodWithRetries(
    Func<Task<bool>> callback, int maxAttempts = numOfTaskAttempts,
    int delay = taskAttemptDelay)
{
    int numOfTries = 0;

    while (!await callback() && ++numOfTries < maxAttempts)
        await Task.Delay(delay);

    return numOfTries < maxAttempts;
}

private static async Task<bool> CallAsyncMethodWithRetries(
    Func<string, Task<bool>> callback, string arg,
    int maxAttempts = numOfTaskAttempts, int delay = taskAttemptDelay)
{
    int numOfTries = 0;

    while (!await callback(arg) && ++numOfTries < maxAttempts)
        await Task.Delay(delay);

    return numOfTries < maxAttempts;
}

private static async Task<bool> CallAsyncMethodWithRetries(
    Func<string, string, Task<bool>> callback, string arg1, string arg2,
    int maxAttempts = numOfTaskAttempts, int delay = taskAttemptDelay)
{
    int numOfTries = 0;

    while (!await callback(arg1, arg2) && ++numOfTries < maxAttempts)
        await Task.Delay(delay);

    return numOfTries < maxAttempts;
}
```

How they are called:

```
bool isSuccess = false;
if (await CallAsyncMethodWithRetries(CreateAndSetTopPuzzlePlayers))
    if (await CallAsyncMethodWithRetries(SetTitleData, PlayfabServerKeys.DailyPuzzle, dailyPuzzle))
        isSuccess = await CallAsyncMethodWithRetries(ResetLeaderboard, PlayfabServerKeys.DailyPuzzle);
```

Any way to reduce the redundant code would be appreciated. I'm still fairly new at async programming, so the solution could be right in front of me and I probably wouldn't know it.

Comment: Related: [Func<> with unknown number of parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22834120/func-with-unknown-number-of-parameters).

Answer (score 3):

There are various ways to approach this, including, as was mentioned in a comment to the question, delegates with a variable number of arguments, and up to using reflection.

But a cleanest and in fact more *functional* approach in these cases is to simply have your `CallAsyncMethodWithRetries` take a `Func<Task<bool>>` as argument, and then you call it with a lambda expression that closes (as in *closure*) over the actual method invocation with the needed arguments, as for example:

```cs
await CallAsyncMethodWithRetries(() => ResetLeaderboard(PlayfabServerKeys.DailyPuzzle));
```

Here is a full example (slightly simplified re your code, I have removed argument defaults): https://dotnetfiddle.net/JVKUYP

Comment: To be clear, you're suggesting that the OP's first method is the answer.

Comment: While my answer is, and only partially, matched by the OP's first snippet, that is just incidental, there is no answer in the OP who is rather thinking overloaded signatures: indeed, I have given an answer that was not even under the radar, and I have in fact explained what's the idea and how it works.

Comment: What do you mean by "not even under the radar"? Do you mean "not even on the radar"?