# c# add parameters to Func

Tags: c#, func

I have these functions:

```
public List<int> GetInts(int someParam)
public List<int> GetMoreInts(int someParam, int anotherParam)
```

I changed the signature of these functions so that they will get an additional optional parameter:

```
public List<int> GetInts(int someParam, int offset = 0)
public List<int> GetMoreInts(int someParam, int anotherParam, int offset = 0)
```

Now, I want to call a wrapper function, which will call these functions with the additional, optional parameter:

```
public List<int> Wrapper(Func<List<int>> queryFunc)
{
    var offset = 5;
    return queryFunc(offset);
}
```

I will call the wrapper this way:

```
List<int> result = Wrapper(() => GetInts(0));
```

How can I accomplish it? How can I add parameters to a Func, when I don't know the signature of the function that the Func points to?

In case the reason I want to do it is relevant:

I have many functions, with different signatures, that query different db tables.
Some of these queries' result set is too big, so I want to use (MySQL) the Limit function:

'some mysql query' limit offset,batchsize

And then concatenate the results at the wrapper function.
So I added additional parameters (offset, batchsize) to some of the functions, And I want the wrapper function to added these parameters to the function that Func points at.

**EDIT:**
I don't understand the reason for the down vote.

I have multiple functions with different signatures which query my db.

The problem is that in some cases, the result set is too big and I get a timeout exception.

Because the result set is too big, I want to get small chunks of result sets, then concatenate them all into the complete result set.

For example: the original result set size is 500K which causes a timeout.

I want to get result sets sized at 1K, 500 times.

That's why I need to control the offset from within the Wrapper, so that at each iteration, I could send the offset, which is incremented after every iteration, as a parameter to the original function.

Comment: You simply don't pass a `Func<List<int>>` but rather a `Func<List<int>, int>`

Comment: Something [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059624/can-i-use-params-in-action-or-func-delegates)?

Comment: I have the 'feeling' that you are doing that kind of "Programming hacks your team will hate Vol 2" thing.

Comment: @Felype I edited the question, tried to explain it better. I don't see a problem with my design but would love to hear suggestions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to make a `Func` that takes the single `int` and returns the `List<int>`.

```
public List<int> Wrapper(Func<int, List<int>> queryFunc)
{
    var offset = 5;
    return queryFunc(offset);
}
```

Then you'd have to use it by passing in lambdas where you call your other functions with the desired params and passing in the lambdas argument as the `offset`.

```
var result1 = Wrapper(o => GetInts(someParam, o));
var result2 = Wrapper(o => GetMoreInts(someParam, anotherParam, o));
```

Though I'm not sure how useful that really is.  If the `offset` is something global you might want to inject it instead of passing it to these functions by making it a field of the class that they belong to.

Comment: If you don't want a return value, try `Action` instead of `Func`.

Comment: Or specify return type of the Func as List

Comment: @Andrei Yeah, missed that part.

Comment: @TânNguyễn Nope, I just forgot to add the return type.

Comment: Actually, your answer is very useful, since the offset will be per function. So I can do something like this: 
var result = Wrapper(offset => GetInts(1,offset), 5)

public List<int> Wrapper(Func<int, List<int>> queryFunc, int offset){
   return queryFunc(offset);
}

And now I can use a different offset each time I use the wrapper for ANY query function, regardless of its signature, which is great

Answer (score 1):

I think you wrapper should look like this:

```
 public List<int> Wrapper(int x, int y, Func<int,int,List<int>> queryFunc)
    {            
        return queryFunc(x, y);            
    }
```

This is if you want to pass the parameter from outside. Also, this is the `wrapper` for the `public List<int> GetMoreInts(int someParam, int anotherParam, int offset = 0)`

I hope I have understood your problem.