# How do I pass a function pointer delegate for a different class in c#

Tags: c#, c++, delegates, function-pointers

In c++,
To a function that takes in a function pointer with void return type, eg:

```
void TakesFun(Func<void ()>  fun ){
    fun();
}
```

Above function can be called in these ways

```
//if foo is a function returning void but is declared in global space and not part of another class
TakesFun(bind(foo));   
//if foo is a function returning void but is declared in class called ClassX and the function is required to be called for object "obj".
TakesFun(bind(ClassX::foo, obj));   
//if foo is a function taking an integer as argument and returning void but is declared in class called ClassX and the function is required to be called for object "obj".
TakesFun(bind(ClassX::foo, obj, 5)); //5 is the argument supplied to function foo
```

Could you help me write C# code for 3 similar function calls? I tried reading up on Delegates, but the examples do not cover all the above 3 cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Backs said, you can define `TakesFun` function like this:

```
void TakesFun(Action action) => action();
```

If you need to pass a parameter, you can use this:

```
void TakesFun<TParam>(Action<TParam> action, TParam p) => action(p);
```

Your 3 examples will be:

```
TakesFun(SomeClass.Foo); // 'Foo' is a static function of 'SomeClass' class
TakesFun(obj.Foo); // 'Foo' is a function of some class and obj is instance of this class
TakesFun(obj.Foo, "parameter"); // as above, but will pass string as parameter to 'Foo'
```

Comment: Could I make the syntax of TakesFun be able to take any number of arguments for the action?

Comment: Sure, with a little trick, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059624/can-i-use-params-in-action-or-func-delegates)

Answer (score 0):

You can always pass an [`Action`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
void TakesFun(Action action)
{
    action();
}
///...
TestFun(() => SomeMethod(1,2,3));
```